# how to open a link in new window using html?

Tags: html

i want to open link in new window instead of new tab. I used "_blank" and "_new" in target but its not working, its open's in new window.

```
<a href="allskills.php" style="text-decoration:none" target="_new">All Skills</a>
or
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" onClick="window.open('allskills.php', '_blank')">All Skills</a>
```

is there any way to open in new window?

Thanks

Comment: read question properly..

Comment: @Quentin seen that question but its not working.

Comment: @SidM seen that question but its not working

Comment: @smAnkurDhanuka — Why would you expect it to work when the accepted answer to the duplicate question is "You can't do that"?

Comment: @Quentin its not working..thats why i ask question and i have already mention that "_blank" or "_new" is not working

Comment: @smAnkurDhanuka — It's not working, because what you want, you can't have, which is what the answer to the duplicate question says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/LtKVQ/)

Try this

```
popupWin = window.open('http://webdesign.about.com/',
'open_window',
'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable,
dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0')
```

Answer (score 1):

FF uses tabs. New window you can open only with Javascript:
`window.open('example.html', 'name', 'settings')`

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_focus